# Kubernetes clusters should not grant CAPSYSADMIN security capabilities

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

In Our AKS, found high severity alerts related to this in Azure Security Center.

What is CAPSYSADMIN meant for?
Is the pods by default enabled with this property?
Because we didnt specifically enabled it in our AKS? Then what will be the reason for this alert ?
And how can we remediate this alert?

Comment: This is done by whoever created the pods. Check the pod definition YAML.

Comment: Yes I checked and there were no property set fo this to enable. Its really strange that why its showing this error eventhough the property is not set

Comment: Could you share the whole alert message from ASC ?

Comment: @mario the alert was same as I given in the issue title. There are no more details available.

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation:

> What is CAPSYSADMIN meant for?

Linux capabilities are a broad topic in itself but in short, as you can read [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

> Starting with kernel 2.2, Linux divides the privileges
> traditionally associated with superuser into distinct units,
> known as capabilities, which can be independently enabled and
> disabled.  Capabilities are a per-thread attribute.

So in other words they are distinct units that can be used to controll privilege escalation in your Linux OS.

And `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is one of them and in fact it is pretty powerfull one. It allows to perform a range of system administration operations, privileged ones that cannot be performed by a normal user. For the full list please refer to [this document](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.

As you can imagine, from security perspective, using this capability is not recommended, unless it is absolutely necessary. This is in line with [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) which basically means *"giving a user account or process only those privileges which are essential to perform its intended function"*.

But let's go back to the context of **kubernetes**, **AKS** and **Azure** as you're probably still curious how all what I mentioned above fits there.

> Is the pods by default enabled with this property?

No, it is not unless you enable it explicitly in a `Pod` definition. So the warning you get it's not about the fact that this capability is used by any of your pods but rather about the possibility that this property can be used by any of your users who are authorized to create new pods in the **AKS** cluster. In other words, at the moment, pods that leverage `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability are allowed to be created on your **AKS** cluster.

Below you can see an example of such a `Pod`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo-4
spec:
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-4
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
```

For more details please refer to [Set capabilities for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container) section in the official kubernetes docs.

You can easily test it on your own and you'll see that the above `Pod` will be successfully created as it is not prohibited now in any way.

You can then `kubectl exec` to such `Pod` and verify that `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability is indeed used by it. Simply run:

```
kubectl exec -it security-context-demo-4 -- /bin/bash
```

Once connected to the `Pod` you can run:

```
capsh --print | grep cap_sys_admin
```

And you'll see that `cap_sys_admin` capability is enabled.

You can check the same in a `Pod` which doesn't use this capability:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo-4-1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-4
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
```

When you `kubectl exec` into it:

```
kubectl exec -ti security-context-demo-4-1 -- /bin/bash
```

and run the same command:

```
capsh --print | grep cap_sys_admin
```

you'll see it's not enabled by default.

#### Solution:

Although **AKS** is a managed kubernetes service and in fact a lot of security layers are already handled for you by Microsoft, you are still granted with quite wide range of responsibilities when it comes to management of your **AKS** cluster. You can e.g. perform some further actions on your own to make it even more secure.

The good news is that you're not left completely alone with such tasks and you're provided with bunch of ready solutions that you can simply apply in your Azure environment.

One of them is **Azure Security Center**, which relieves you of the burden to detect new potential threats in your current setup on your own. As you can read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/release-notes?WT.mc_id=modinfra-26657-abartolo#new-recommendations-for-hardening-kubernetes-clusters-in-preview) the recommendation **Kubernetes clusters should not grant CAPSYSADMIN security capabilities** is a part of **New recommendations for hardening Kubernetes clusters** which are still in preview, so you may have not seen them before:

> #### New recommendations for hardening Kubernetes clusters (in preview)
>
> The following recommendations allow you to further harden your
> Kubernetes clusters
>
> - **Kubernetes clusters should not use the default namespace**  - To protect against unauthorized access for ConfigMap, Pod, Secret,
>   Service, and ServiceAccount resource types, prevent usage of the
>   default namespace in Kubernetes clusters.
> - **Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials**  - To prevent a potentially compromised Pod resource
>   from running API commands against Kubernetes clusters, disable
>   automounting API credentials.
> - **Kubernetes clusters should not grant CAPSYSADMIN security capabilities**

> Then what will be the reason for this alert ?

Given the above, this question can be answered: **to give you possibility to improve your kubernetes cluster security by reducing the potential attack surface of your containers.** But it's entirely up to you if you decide to follow this recommendation or not.

So much for the threat detection part. What about the remediation part ?

> And how can we remediate this alert?

[Azure policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview) is the answer for that. You may have heard about them already. Fortunately to remediate this particular threat you don't have to write your own custom policy as Azure provides [built-in  policy definitions for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/policy-reference) and you can simply leverage them on your **AKS** cluster.

In the first column you are provided with [direct link to your Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2Fd2e7ea85-6b44-4317-a0be-1b951587f626), which will bring you to the policy definition page, where you can examine its details and where it can be assigned to a particular subscription and recource group:

[image]

[image]

For more details please refer to:

- [Understand Azure Policy for Kubernetes clusters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/policy-for-kubernetes)

Other useful links:

- [New recommendations for hardening Kubernetes clusters (in preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/release-notes?WT.mc_id=modinfra-26657-abartolo#new-recommendations-for-hardening-kubernetes-clusters-in-preview)
- [full list of Azure Policy built-in policy definitions for kubernetes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#kubernetes)
- [Azure Policy built-in definitions for Azure Kubernetes Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/policy-reference)
- [What is Azure Policy?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview)
- [capabilities(7) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)